# Import phonegap/cordova project into Intel XDK

Tags: android, html, cordova, intel, intel-xdk

I am a programmar at novice level.
I have a project that I would like to import at Intel XDK.

[Link to the project](https://github.com/akocmark/Fertiller)

The project structure has been made in Phonegap version 2.1.
I am trying to inport the HTML5 project within Intel XDK with no luck.
I'm getting the error : index.html is missing!

Do you know if there is a way to get this project work into Intel XDK?
The html files are under the directory of assets/view. But there is no index.html.

Hope you guys could help me figure this out.

With friendly regards,

Mirjam.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest thing to do would be to use a blank template to create a new project and then copy your www directory from your existing project into the www of that blank template project.

It's not clear which of your html files is the equivalent of index.html, but you might want to just re-use the index.html file that is created by the template as your index.html file and work from there.

Just a note, in general, it is hard to build multi-page hybrid apps (like yours appears to be) if you are going to be using APIs that are implemented via Cordova plugins. If you do not need any of the Cordova plugin APIs (that is, you are only using standard HTML5 APIs that are built into the webview), then you can get away with it. If you do plan to extend your app to take advantage of Cordova plugins (core, XDK or third-party) you might want to consider creating a single-page app.

Another approach to consider is displaying the "other" pages using the inAppBrowser plugin. This assumes that the "other" pages do not need access to device APIs.

It's hard to provide a precise "here's how to do it" without having a deeper understanding of how your app is structured and where you intend to go with it.